"Vector too long" error when importing DWG file to QGIS
I'm trying to import a .dwg file (a detailed aerial image) to QGIS. I used Project >> Import DWG/DXF and when I click "Import" it says that 5287 entities have been processed, but then an error message pops up saying "vector too long". I cannot proceed after that.
I am using QGIS version 3.34. The .dwg file was provided by a third party, and I do not have Autocad (nor am I familiar with it).  I'm not sure what to try next! Any help or direction is appreciated.
